# Extract tar.gz file (Dataset)

Tags: machine-learning

I want to extract my file which is a medical image dataset (2.64 GB).

I used `tar -xzf filename.tar.gz` in ubuntu :

[image: ubuntu]

I tried to extract it using 7-zip in Windows :

[image: image 7zip]

Comment: seems the `.tar.gz` file is corrupt. Can you post a link to the file, if it's publicly available?

Comment: maybe consider re-downloading from a different source. You should note that the dataset   is encrypted. For windows, using Cyberduck seems like a decent alternative, please see [here](http://fcon_1000.projects.nitrc.org/indi/retro/atlas_download.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @philshem

File link: [Link](http://fcon_1000.projects.nitrc.org/indi/retro/atlas_download.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SuperKogito. I tried with Cyberduck and I decrypt the file but I have the same problem !

Comment: did you request the password as instructed on the page?

Comment: Yes, I got the password and I used it to decrypt the file